# How parse string in javascript with html char

Tags: javascript

For example: I have this string `var s = 'Some text .... &#9749;'`. How decode in JavaScript to `var s = 'Some text .... \u2615'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you have tried so far and not even that sure what exactly you want in your case, but…

```
var s='Some text .... &#9749;';
s=s.replace(/&#(\d*);/g,function(full,number){
  return '\\u'+Number(number).toString(16);
});
```

returns "Some text .... \u2615".

```
var s='Some text .... &#9749;';
s=s.replace(/&#(\d*);/g,function(full,number){
  return String.fromCharCode(Number(number));
});
```

returns "Some text .... ☕".

Instead of `fromCharCode` `fromCodePoint` is also possible.

Comment: Btw: below the second code it displays a coffee cup unicode symbol (U+2615)—for those who can’t see it.